# Set Active class for Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, carousel, bootstrap-5

Iam having a bootstrap carousel in which the images are dynamic(from backend api) so i could not set active class for the slides ..If i use active className in hardcode, all slides are active at same time ..
How to do it dynamically

So far i have tried setting active class using jquery.. I got all the elements inside  **carousel-inner** and then used **addClass and removeClass** but it did not help me

[**sandbox link click here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/5mne02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use jquery in react project. take look on other npm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel

and if you are using react-bootstrap then check

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Comment: Thanks dude.. Previously i was using MDBootstrap,
React Bootstrap carousel made it very easy for backend data's

Comment: yup, happy codding